# Fourier Analysis Help - $\mathcal L^2$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{e_k | e_k(x)= e^{ikx}/\sqrt{2\pi\,}\}$ be the orthonormal basis in $\mathcal L^2$ per.
I first have to use this basis define two infinite dimensional orthogonal subspaces of $\mathcal L^2$ per.

Then I have to show whether the completeness relation holds for:
 $A = \{e_k | k \in\Bbb Z \setminus 3\Bbb Z\}$?

1. What would the two infinite dimensional orthogonal subspaces be in $\mathcal L^2$ per?
2. How do I prove that the completeness relation holds for $A$?

Answer (score 0):

For 1, write $\mathbb{Z}$ as the union of two disjoint infinite subsets, $\mathbb{Z} = A \cup B$ and look at the subspaces spanned by $\{ e_k \}_{k\in A}$ and $\{ e_k \}_{k\in B}$.

For 2, think some more about 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've found the norm and inner product of the set but how does this relate to the completeness relation? Does the set have to have inner product 0 and norm 1 to complete?